# File uploading in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Been trying tons of things to save a file upload into the proper directory in Laravel.  I have the following in my controller.  The $files and $folder variables are correct.  The folder is being created properly but the file will not save to the folder:

```
$files = $request->file('current_plan_year_claims_data_file_1');
$folder = public_path(). "\storage\\$id";

if (!File::exists($folder)) {
    File::makeDirectory($folder, 0775, true, true);
}

if (!empty($files)) {
    foreach($files as $file) {
        // Storage::disk('local')->put($file->getClientOriginalName(), file_get_contents($file));
        Storage::disk(['drivers' => 'local', 'root' => $folder])->put($file->getClientOriginalName(), file_get_contents($file));

        // Storage::put($file->getClientOriginalName(), $folder);

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message of some kind?

Comment: Did it upload to the wrong place or it didn't even uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try this code. error in your `storage::disk` line. write **driver** instead of **drivers**.

```
    $files = $request->file('current_plan_year_claims_data_file_1');
    $folder = public_path(). "\storage\\$id";


     if (!File::exists($folder)) {
        File::makeDirectory($folder, 0775, true, true);
    }

    if (!empty($files)) {
        foreach($files as $file) {
             Storage::disk(['driver' => 'local', 'root' => $folder])->put($file->getClientOriginalName(), file_get_contents($file));
        }
    }
```